# Probability of a board game

Tags: probability

In the board game Far Space Foundry, part of the set up involves selecting several product types to be available during the game for manufacturing.  In a four-player game, five different product types are selected, without regard to order.

In the base game, there are eight different product types available. The Extra Product" expansion to the base game adds an additional six product types  for 14 total product types.

1.)  If you play with the \Extra Product" expansion and insist that at least one of the six new product types from that expansion is used in each game, how many different configurations of five product types are possible?

2.) The  Ether  Ore"  expansion  adds  another  three  product  types,  but  with  the  caveat  that  at  most  two  of  these  can  be  selected  for  use  in  any  given game.  If you played with both the Extra Product expansion and the EtherOre expansion, how many different configurations of five product types are possible?

Comment: For problem 2, are you also stipulating that at least one card be used from each expansion?

Comment: Only up to 2 of the 3 new product types can be used

Comment: So a configuration which uses $0$ products from the Extra Production expansion is a valid configuration for problem 2? As is a configuration which uses $0$ products from the Ether Ore expansion? As is a configuration which only uses products from the base game?

Comment: Also, I apologize, I've been using "cards" and "products" interchangeably...I somehow made an assumption that each product is represented by a card in the board game.

Comment: Yes, that scenario is valid

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

1) There are ${14 \choose 5}$ ways to pick $5$ products from the$14$ product types in the base game and Extra Product expansion. Of these ways, ${8 \choose 5}$ of them involve picking only products not in the Extra Product expansion. So the number of ways to pick $5$ products from the $14$ product types such that at least one product comes from the expansion is ${14 \choose 5} - {8 \choose 5}$.

2) There are ${17 \choose 5}$ ways to pick $5$ products between the base game and all the expansions. Of these, ${14 \choose 2}$ of these ways involve picking three products from the EtherOre expansion (once those $3$ products from the EtherOre expansion are chosen, you must pick $2$ more products from the remaining $14$). Thus, there is a total of ${17 \choose 5} - {14 \choose 2}$ valid configurations.

Comment: Hey, not sure if you'll respond since it's been a while, but why do you not have to account for 14 choose 1? Is it included in the 14 choose 2?

Comment: The number of ways of picking $0,1$ or $2$ products from the Ether Ore expansion is accounted for in the ${17 \choose 5}$. However, the ${17 \choose 5}$ also accounts for the number of ways of picking $3$ product from the Ether Ore expansion (which isn't allowed) which is why we subtract the ${14 \choose 2}$ to compensate.

To obtain ${14 \choose 2}$, I first looked at the number of ways of choosing 3 products from the ether expansion (which is one) and multiplied it by the number of ways to pick the remaining 2 products from the remaining 14 available which is ${14 \choose 2}$.